# Determining the number of gallons of fuel that the car used on the trip.

Tags: gre-exam

> [image]

My answer was (C), where I was thinking while I was solving how the unit could be Gallons only, but the correct answer is (A), I do not know why my answer is wrong and why (A) is the correct answer, could anyone help me please?

Comment: I'm not an expert at integrals myself but I would thing the fact that distance is only speed multiplied by time  if speed is constant. distance under acceleration etc. changes ( admittedly that's related to velocity, not speed).

Comment: I suspect that in your dimensional analysis you didn't take into account that $dt$ contributes as well.

Comment: I do not see the relation between your answer and my question. @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: the difference between your choice and the other one is a factor of t in the numerator of each part of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $E(v(t))$ is $\dfrac{\text{miles}}{\text{gallon}}$, or in calculus terms, $\frac{dm}{dg}$. Your speed is $\frac{dm}{dt}$ (miles per hour). So to get $\frac{dg}{dt}$, the derivative you need, it is $\dfrac{\frac{dm}{dt}}{\frac{dg}{dt}}$, which is $\dfrac{v(t)}{E(v(t))}$.

Answer (score 1):

So, think about it like this - you want the integral to give you the amount of gallons you use. That means the *area under your curve* is going to be the gallons you used in relation to the *time* you spent driving.

Just look at what each one is telling you in the equation itself:

A) $\frac{v(t)}{E(v(t))}$

Here right away we see that we are saying $\frac{\frac{miles}{hour}}{\frac{miles}{gallon}} = \frac{gallon*miles}{miles*hour} = \frac{gallon}{hour} $ which means we're looking at gallons per time unit (hours) which means when we integrate this function we will be able to say we used exactly *this many* gallons in this many hours. Of course, this is somewhat trivial if it's a linear function, but let's say you're constantly changing your speed - well that effects your mpg and so here we've taken your speed completely out of it because, honestly, we don't care at the end of the day about your speed: just how hungry your car was for that sweet, sweet Dino juice.

anyways, take a look at the other functions and see what you're *really* getting when you integrate them. ;)